# '//noinspection' keyword list for IDEA

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, code-inspection

I can use `//noinspection` statement to <strike>disable</strike> suppress some types of code inspection in IDEA IDE (WebStorm, PhpStorm, ...):

```js
// noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
```

Where can I find a list of all inspections available for this statement?

UPDATE: I'm looking for keywords list for JavaScript.

Comment: *"I can use //noinspection statement to disable some types of code inspection*" It's not disabling -- it's suppressing them (they are still run, just not reported for that line/statement). You can insert such comment via Alt+Enter/light bulb menu https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections

Comment: https://gist.github.com/discordier/ed4b9cba14652e7212f5 .. or look inside the JS plugin file and iterate the inspection names there...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, at this time (May 2022) JetBrains does not appear to keep an up-to-date list of inspection IDs (what I'll call `shortName`s) as part of their [public online documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/code-inspection.html) for all products (e.g. there is a page called [List of Java inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/list-of-java-inspections.html), but it doesn't appear to include the `shortName`s).

If you are a JetBrains customer and this is something you would like then I would encourage you to send feedback to them with suggestions for how the software could be improved. (e.g. on [a community](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000475204-Where-to-find-a-list-of-all-code-inspection-names) [forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205816679-Need-noinspection-reference) or [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11269/Improving-how-the-developer-can-respond-to-inspection-warnings)).

Thankfully, there are some ways to ascertain these `shortName`s:

### 1. Use the context menu

Right-click near the "red squiggle", select "Show Context Actions", click directly on the arrow, and click "Suppress for statement". This should generate a comment above the line, e.g. `// noinspection NpmUsedModulesInstalled`, which then suppresses the inspection for the following line (making the "red squiggle" go away)
[image: context menu in WebStorm IDE highlighting expansion arrow then "suppress for statement" on submenu]

### 2. Peek at a cheat sheet

Various people have uploaded (unofficial) lists of the inspection names for convenient reference. Here are some:

- https://gist.github.com/discordier/ed4b9cba14652e7212f5
- https://gist.github.com/pieterb/e74f92b8ac40e18ead1d4fd49b97660f
- https://gist.github.com/delameter/8875d19aa4c09afd2eba3801a970abf4

### 3. Dig into the IDE's installation files

In my case, I searched through files in my WebStorm installation folder (e.g. `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\WebStorm\ch-0\221.5080.193`) and found `plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/lib/JavaScriptLanguage.jar` (which is a compressed archive, using ZIP format, [whose contents can can be extracted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html)) and found that the `META-INF\plugin.xml` file it contained had the information I wanted in the `shortName` attribute of elements that looked like this:

```xml
<localInspection
  language="JavaScript"
  groupPath="JavaScript and TypeScript" 
  shortName="JSRemoveUnnecessaryParentheses"
  key="unnecessary.parentheses.display.name"
  groupKey="js.code.style.issues.group.name"
  enabledByDefault="true"
  level="INFORMATION"
  cleanupTool="true"
  implementationClass="com.intellij.lang.javascript.inspections.JSRemoveUnnecessaryParenthesesInspection"
/>
```

Comment: Sql inspections can be found at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\%PRODUCT_NAME%\plugins\DatabaseTools\lib\database-plugin.jar::META-INF\SqlPlugin.xml . Check the suppressId tag for your inspection (not all of them have suppressId tags though). There are 48 total currently (way more than listed in the cheat sheets).

Answer (score 1):

The website of the IDEA IDE has a page listing these:

> **Disable and suppress inspections**
>
> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2019.1/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html

Comment: Any idea where I can find a similar list for WebStorm / JS? I looked in what I thought was the equivalent documentation (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections) but cannot find them anywhere.

Comment: Nevermind, I found what I needed here: https://gist.github.com/discordier/ed4b9cba14652e7212f5